# My iOS/MacOS devices are unable to resolve my bonjour/zeroconf service created on Windows

Tags: ios, windows, macos, bonjour

I'm hoping someone may have experience with this and could provide some help. I've created a Windows bonjour service using this [bonjour package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bonjour) from npm. When created, my iOS/MacOSx device is not able to resolve the service and get the required IP + txt record information. However, my Android device is able to discover and resolve the service using the jmDNS Library. I feel there is something that is implemented differently in the MacOSx/iOS that I don't quite understand.

I'm able to discover the name in the [Discovery Browser](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/discovery-dns-sd-browser/id305441017) and dns-sd tool but it doesn't show any information.

[image: Bonjour service running on Windows]

I've also tried to use my Cordova app to discover the service and this just shows the service as having been "Added" but it never gets to the "Resolved" state.

When running the same service on my MacOS machine, everything works as it should. The service is resolved and I'm able to get information on the service. It also works in the iOS app.

[image: Bonjour service running on MacOS]

If anyone has any ideas or input, I would be forever grateful! This problem has had be bogged down for 3 days now.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, thank goodness. I've solved my own problem. Turns out this iOS/MacOSx required me to specify the hostname as well as the service name. This wasn't in the documentation.

After adding a "host" field to my published service everything worked as it should!